# Getting string value from nssarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I define an array in the 'interface' section of the view controller thus:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *images;
```

I load it in viewDidLoad:

```
self.images = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia1_1x"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia2_1x"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia3_1x"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia4_1x"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia5_1x"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia6_1x"]];
```

Then I want to set the image in a UIImage from the array. I can hard code the name of the image, and it works fine:

```
self.currentImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sophia4_1x.png"];
```

But if I try to get the value from the array:

```
self.currentImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.images[row]];
```

I get "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

and I just...don't........*understand!*

Comment: You have an array of UIImage and you're trying to use one of those as the name of an image.  The exception message, if you bother to read it, tells you that a UIImage object is being "sent" a message that should be "sent" to an NSString.  (-1 and a close vote for not including the exception message and stack trace.)

Answer (score 4):

Your array contains UIImage objects, not strings, so you can't pass `self.images[row]` to the `imageNamed:` method. To get an image, you just need to access the row you want in the array,

```
self.currentImage.image = self.images[row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to save an array of strings, and then use a string to load an image?

If so, your code would look like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageNames;
```

And the code to load it:

```
self.imageNames =  @[
 @"sophia2_1x",
 @"sophia3_1x",
 @"sophia4_1x",
 @"sophia5_1x",
 @"sophia6_1x"
];
```

Then your code to load an image would work:

```
self.currentImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageNames[row]];
```

If you really wanted an array of images then relmar's solution would give you that.